# Why/how does type casting solve the null safety error in some cases?

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-null-safety, typecasting-operator

After upgrading to Flutter 3, I am going through my code and correcting null safety errors. Occasionally, I get an error that is fixed by type casting, but I don't understand why. Can anyone help me understand this or point me to a good explanation?

Here's an example:
The code below throws the error: *The property 'latitude' can't be unconditionally accessed because the receiver can be 'null'.Try making the access conditional (using '?.') or adding a null check to the target ('!').*

```
CameraPosition( target: LatLng( _initLoc.latitude, _initLoc.longitude), zoom: 18)
```

When I use _initLoc? it throws this error: *The argument type 'double?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'double'.*

I can fix it by changing the ? to !, but prefer not to use ! if possible. I discovered that I can keep the ? as long as I cast the latitude and longitude as doubles like below:

```
CameraPosition(target: LatLng( _initLoc?.latitude as double, _initLoc?.longitude as double),zoom: 18 )
```

Any explanation for why this works would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Have you read https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety ?

Answer (score 0):

It is very simple. Just read any variable declared with ? at the end of datatype as 'type' or 'null'. For example if you declared a variable as 'double?', you should read this as 'double' or 'null'. Means the value you are assigning to the variable could be 'double' or 'null'.

The '_initLoc' variable is a nullable type. So it either can be 'type' or 'null'. If it is 'null', you cannot access 'latitude' param inside '_initLoc' object. The '_initLoc?.location' says the compiler only access 'location' param only if '_initLoc' param is not null.

The code '_initLoc?.latitude as double' works as long as '_initLoc' is not null. If it results in null, you again get an error says 'null is not a subtype of double'.

The proper solution would be go to the declaration of '_initLoc' and make it non nullable(without ? at the end of datatype) or if it could be null, pass default value if '_initLoc' is 'null', like `CameraPosition(target: LatLng( _initLoc?.latitude ?? 0.0, _initLoc?.longitude ?? 0.0),zoom: 18 )`

The '_initLoc?.latitude ?? 0.0' line says, if '_initLoc' is not null access '_initLoc.latitude' param. It '_initLoc' is null, pass '0.0'.

Read the [null-safety documentation](https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety) for deep understanding.

Hope it helps! Happy coding :)